# Laravel - I want to get all the messages between the auth user and the receiver

Tags: laravel, controller, chat

I have a users table, a message table and a user-message table.
i want to get all the messages between the authenticated user and the receiver.

here are the tables and the models:

the users table and model are obvious.

Message model :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Message extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'parent_id', 'message', 'type','status',
    ];
    public function user_messages(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\UserMessage');
    }

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','user_messages','message_id','sender_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

User_message model :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserMessage extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'message_id', 'sender_id', 'receiver_id','type','seen_status','deliver_status',
    ];

    public function message(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Message');
    }
}
```

Message table :

```
   * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('parent_id')->nullable();
            $table->longText('message')->nullable();
            $table->integer('type')->default(1)->comment('1 : message , 2 : file');
            $table->integer('status')->default(1);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

User_message table :

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user_messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('message_id');
        $table->integer('sender_id');
        $table->integer('receiver_id');
        $table->integer('type')->default(0)->comment('1 : groupe message , 0 : personal message');
        $table->integer('seen_status')->default(0)->comment('1 : seen');
        $table->integer('deliver_status')->default(0)->comment('1 : delivered');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

so all i want to know is how the logic inside the controller function will be.

Comment: Your database structure is really bad. If you want to retrieve messages between to users you have to add a middle table named conversations, and you can have the id's of both users that are involved in the conversation and then you can return the messages that belong only to that conversation. The way you created its very convoluted to query the messages you want.

Comment: i added a middle table between users and messages it's called user_message as above

Comment: then return UserMessage::find($user_message->id)->messages->get();

Comment: @dz0nika your logic helped a great deal !

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

```
public function getMessages($id, $ids){
        $final_messages_list = array();
        $auth_id = $id;
        $friend_id = $ids;
        $messages = UserMessage::where('sender_id',$auth_id)->where('receiver_id',$friend_id)->orderby('created_at','desc')->get();
        foreach($messages as $message){
            $final_messages_list[] = $message->message;
        } 
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 200,
            'messages' => $final_messages_list,
            
        ]);

        
    }
```